# how to evaluate integral: $\int_{0}^{10} x^2 e^{-x^2/2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to evaluate this integral $$\int_{0}^{10} x^2 e^{\frac{-x^2}2} dx$$ but I'm not sure how. The problem also states that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2 e^{\frac{-x^2}\beta} dx=\frac{\beta^{\frac{1+1}\beta}\Gamma(\frac1\alpha)}{\alpha^2}$$ but I don't know what that means. Can somebody point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Your integrand is so small for $x \gt 10$ that the error from integrating out to $\infty$ is very small.  When I do the second integral in[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2*e%5E(-x%5E2%2Fa)+from+0+to+infinity), it gives $\frac {\sqrt \pi \beta^{3/2}}{4}$  It seems strange to have $\alpha$ on the right and not on the left.

Comment: What is $\alpha$ in the second equation? It seems as if it's missing from the left-hand side.

Comment: @theonlygusti do not put gibberish in the edit summary. it will be rejected. actually explain what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Start with integration by parts by letting $u = x$, $dv = xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$. The latter can be integrated with an obvious substitution.

You should now be able to reduce the problem to an expression that includes this:

$\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$, with the appropriate bounds.

You can do one more substitution (try $y = \frac x{\sqrt 2}$). You will now have this integral $\int e^{-y^2}dy$ with the appropriate bounds.

Unfortunately, there is no elementary antiderivative for that integrand. At this point, you will need recourse to the special [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) to express the final value.

Comment: You did beat me by 3 seconds !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici LOL, I'm relieved! :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You should've still posted your solution. I always find alternative perspectives in different answers (perhaps slight differences) that I find valuable. Especially comes in handy to provide a different explanation to different students.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer. What I was typing was identical to what Deepak answered !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici well, ok then : ) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

*This is more a comment than an answer.*

Using what Deepak answered, you should find that $$\int x^2\,e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
   x$$ where appears the error function (which, as said, is not elementary).

Using the given bounds $$\int_0^{10} x^2\,e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{erf}\left(5 \sqrt{2}\right)-\frac{10}{e^{50}}$$

As Ross Millikan  commented the second term is quite negligible $(\frac{10}{e^{50}}\approx 1.93 \times 10^{-21})$ and we can just focus on the first one.

For $x >2$, a rather good approximation is simply
$$\mathrm{erf}\!\left(x\right)\approx  1-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi } x}$$ and, again, the exponential term makes the result to be very close to $1$.

So, you result is very close to $$\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\approx 1.253314137315500251207883$$ while the "exact" result would be $\approx 1.253314137315500251205935$.

Jus for your curiosity, I give below the value of $$I_n=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\int_{0}^{n} x^2 e^{-x^2/2}\, dx$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & I_n \\
 1 & 0.198748043098799 \\
 2 & 0.738535870050889 \\
 3 & 0.970709113465112 \\
 4 & 0.998866015710215 \\
 5 & 0.999984559501709 \\
 6 & 0.999999925116231 \\
 7 & 0.99999999986955 \\
 8 & 0.99999999999992 \\
 9 & 1.00000000000000
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: A very neat and practical approach. +1

Answer (score 0):

The first definite integral has no simple antiderivative. Maybe you can
expand
\[
e^{-x^{2}/2} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{2n}}{n!2^{n}},
\]
and integrate term by term. And you get the series
\[
\int_{0}^{10}x^{2} e^{-x^{2}/2} dx 
= \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^{n}10^{2n + 3}}{n!2^{n}(2n + 3)}.
\]

For all sufficiently large $n$, the terms consist of
alternating monotonoically decreasing sequences, and
so you get an absolute error of at most 
$\leq \frac{10^{2N + 3}}{N!2^{N}(2N + 3)}$.

That is,
\[
\left| \int_{0}^{10}x^{2} e^{-x^{2}/2} dx 
- \sum_{n \leq N - 1} \frac{(-1)^{n}10^{2n + 3}}{n!2^{n}(2n + 3)} 
\right|
\leq \frac{10^{2N + 3}}{N!2^{N}(2N + 3)}
\]
for all sufficienly large $N$.

On the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}$, 
use the change of variables $u = \beta x^{2}$ 
and the Gamma function
\[
\Gamma(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{s - 1}du. 
\]
Then you will get something which contains the Gamma function.

Comment: May be, I made some mistakes but $\log_{10}\left(\frac{10^{2N + 3}}{N!2^{N}(2N + 3)} \right)$ increases up to $N=50$, becomes $0$ around $N=134$. So, if $\epsilon=10^{-6}$,  $150$ terms would be needed.

Comment: From $N \approx 150$ onwards, nevertheless, I hope the approximation gets faster.

Comment: Basically, it takes two extra terms for going from $\epsilon=10^{-k}$ to $\epsilon=10^{-k-1}$. But the problem is that we should need to sum and subtract incredibly big numbers first. For $N=50$, the corresponding term is $\approx 2.835\times 10^{21}$.

Comment: I gave up on that.